# How to find generators of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ in Sage

Tags: abstract-algebra, sagemath

I don't know anything about Sage, but I need to compute generators of $\mathbb{Z}_p$, $p=463$. How can I do?

Comment: If your question is about multiplicative generators, you should write something like $\mathbb Z_p^{\times}$ to indicate that you talk about the multiplicative group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what you're asking for, but if you want the generators of the multiplicative group of units in $\mathbb{F}_{463}$, then you can do

```
sage: F = GF(463)
sage: [n for n in F if n.is_primitive_root()]
```

If you just want a single generator of $\mathbb{F}_{463}^{\times}$, you can instead do

```
sage: F.primitive_element()
```

Or maybe you're asking about generators of the additive group $\mathbb{Z}/p$, in which case another answer addresses that. Or maybe you're asking about the $p$-adics? (The notation $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ is ambiguous.)

Comment: Thanks for the downvote with no explanation.

Comment: I did not downvote, but I think you should not answer "no effort" questions. It encourages uploading questions without any context, or tryings.

Comment: @DietrichBurde What do you think about this answering future questions of this sort?

Comment: @Chickenmancer It is not important what I think, but rather what the community thinks. And, for example, [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27923/how-to-prevent-no-clue-questions) has some good arguments, why you should not encourage "no clue" questions.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, insofar as you (and all of us) are members of this community, of course it matters what you think. I find some of the arguments at that post distasteful because they are very unwelcoming. Regarding this particular question, in addition to downvoting the question itself, I think that people could have provided feedback as to what was lacking. The poster appears to be new to the site, and I can't imagine that they are feeling encouraged to ask more questions. I would treat an experienced poster asking such a question differently than a new one.

Comment: @JohnPalmieri I agree with you to a certain extend. Still, I find it disappointing if people misuse this site for a homework machine and don't try anything. A post starting with "I don't know anything about this, but I need..." doesn't deserve an answer. In other areas, this would be accepted by all people, I think. If someone asks " I do not understand this sentence in English, because I have no idea about English", everyone would reply "Please first open a dictionary, or a gramar yourself".

Answer (score 0):

All the non-zero elements of $\Bbb{Z}_{463}$ are generators because 463 is prime.

For $\Bbb{Z}_m$ where $m$ is composite, then all non-zero elements of $g\in\Bbb{Z}_m$ where $\gcd{g,m}=1$ are generators.

Comment: I think it's not true because 4 is not a generator of $\mathbb{Z}_5$ despite $gcd(4,5)=1$. In $\mathbb{Z}_m$ if $gcd(a,m)=1$ then we can say $\exists a^{-1}$

Comment: @Dan_Mir You are incorrect, because $4$ is a generator: $4=4$,  $4+4=3$, $4+4+4=2$, $4+4+4+4=1$, and $4+4+4+4+4=0$ modulo $5$.

Comment: One must distinguish between additive generators of $(\mathbb Z_n,+)$ and multiplicative generators of $(\mathbb Z_n^{\times},\cdot)$. The answer is true for the former case. So, @Dan_Mir, $4$ is indeed a generator of $\mathbb Z_5$, but not of $\mathbb Z_5^{\times}$.